# How to list all usages for all methods of a class in Eclipse Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I'm working with a large Java project, re-writing many classes adapting to new data patterns. For that, I'll need a map representation of all references for each method of all classes, in order to see the level of changes that must be done. 
I know how to do it one-by-one with References->Project, but how should I proceed to obtain a listing of all references for all methods of a class?

A text listing should be enough, like:

```
 Class myClass->GetSomething()
    --file1.java  line 232
    --file2.java  line 587 
 Class myClass->GetSomethingMore()
   --file5.java  line 23
```

and so on....

Comment: I don't know a tool for method listing (and I don't see much use as renaming will change all references wherever they are without the need to know that the references exist) but for dependency analysis on class level I like [X-Ray](http://xray.inf.usi.ch/xray.php).

Answer (score 0):

Is "find references" to your class itself not doing what you need?

Comment: Is not enough when I have a class with more than 50 methods, would be better if I could see all references in a single list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux machine use the grep command on the file. This would be easiest way to find all references.

Syntax:

```
grep 'word' filename
grep 'string1 string2'  filename
cat otherfile | grep 'something'
command | grep 'something'
```

Usage:

Search /etc/passwd for boo user:

```
$ grep boo /etc/passwd
```

You can search recursively i.e. read all files under each directory for a string "boo"

```
$ grep -r "boo" /etc/
```

You can use the ‘type’ and ‘find’ command in Dos/Windows to get the equivalent output of the UNIX ‘cat’ and ‘grep’ commands.

Usage:
To find occurance of boo in all the files within current directory.

```
C:>find “boo” *
```

Comment: Sorry to say friend but that would be a plain occurrence listing and not a reference listing. What would be if we have methods of different classes with same names?

Comment: may be what you are trying might be provided by any of these products - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis